# Struct with a volatile member no longer a POD according to MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, volatile

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

extern "C"
{
    struct thread_shared_struct
    {
        volatile uint32_t ccr;
    };

    struct thread_shared_struct getStuff();
}

static_assert(std::is_pod<thread_shared_struct>::value, "thread_shared_struct isn't a POD");

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    thread_shared_struct m = getStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

See [this code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/k5ya7t)

Of course this example doesn't make a lot of sense, but it is a minimal reproduction of my issue from a much larger code base.

With GCC (trunk) and Clang (trunk), this works fine.

With MSVC (x64, 19.22), the static_assert fails and getStuff() generates an error because it attempts to return a type that is not compatible with the C calling convention.

If "volatile" is removed, everything works fine.

Is MSVC in the wrong to think that thread_shared_struct is not a POD type?

The extern "C" part is in a C header that needs to stay as is. How could I use it from C++?

Comment: Note that the notion of `pod` and so `std::is_pod` are deprecated.

Comment: Sound like a bug in MSVC to me. I suggest you don't use `std::is_pod` any more.

Comment: When I implement getStuff() I get a warning, not an error. Maybe this warning is indeed a bug, and it works anyway? But yeah, hopefully someone knows more details about this, or maybe it's time to make the transition to clang on windows :p. I would probably try and contact MS support. Or just try it out (if it is indeed only a warning), once compiled and it is not optimized away (should test each use of it, where it might be), I guess it should work on any windows system. Depending on your circumstances, this might be acceptable (though the longer I think about this, probably not).

Comment: Ok, thanks for pod, I try to keep up, but I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/trivial-standard-layout-and-pod-types?view=vs-2019):

> When a class or struct is both trivial and standard-layout, it is a POD (Plain Old Data) type.

It later describes literal types, including the following condition:

> Additionally, all its non-static data members and base classes must be literal types and not volatile.

There is no mention of "volatile" anywhere else on the page.

This all matches what we find [in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types).

Therefore, I conclude it's a compiler bug.

---

> getStuff() generates an error because it attempts to return a type that is not compatible with the C calling convention.

Actually, this is just a warning (C4190), which you could disable, if you wanted. Visual Studio on x86_64 only has one calling convention (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019)). Your code will still work fine. VS is just warning you that the type won't work if you actually try to use it in C. `extern "C"` does not mean compiling as C.

However, it is true that getting this warning suggests the bug is indeed in the compiler, rather than simply in the implementation of `std::is_pod`.

---

Also, I would recommend avoiding POD terminology and the `std::is_pod` trait in new code, since they are [deprecated from C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod).

---

> The extern "C" part is in a C header that needs to stay as is. How could I use it from C++?

Anything that doesn't *actually* require the type to fit VS's definition of "POD", type trait notwithstanding, should be fine.